# Add values from db to array, sort and display

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am getting some values from a mysql database, but the values in the db are not in order. I want to order the days of the week as SUN, MON, TUE, etc. and display the corresponding values from the db table. I am currently displaying the values from the db without sorting. And I add the values to an array. How can I sort and show the values in an html table? This is my code

```
<?php 
$q3 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM stores_op_hours WHERE Store_Id='$stid' ");
?>
<table class="table ophours">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">

        <tr><th>Day</th><th>Open Time</th><th>Close Time</th></tr>
    </thead>
<?php 
$myarray = array();
while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($q3)){

    $day = $rw['Day_Name'];
    $op = $rw['Open_Time'];
    $cl = $rw['Close_Time'];
    //$day = strtoupper($day);

    $myarray[] = array("day" => $day, "open" => $op, "close" => $cl);
?>  
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><?php echo $day; ?></td><td><?php echo $op; ?></td><td><?php echo $cl; ?></td></tr>
    </tbody>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is the `ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)` solution. Then in the query you would specify the sort order for the Day_Name field, like so:

```
$q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM stores_op_hours WHERE Store_Id=%d 
order by field(Day_Name,'SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT')",(int) $stid);
```

Comment: I don't get any results from the query now

Comment: Typo in @Erik's string should read "... field(Day_Name,..." and not Day_name

Comment: Also, it should not cycle back to 'SUN', so the whole thing should look like "order by field(Day_Name,'SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT')"

Comment: @Webomatik, I got the answer after some tinkering of his code, can you approve the edit to his answer?

Answer (score 0):

So the final edit (thanks to @Erik Dohmen) should look like:

```
$q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM stores_op_hours WHERE Store_Id=%d 
order by field(Day_Name,'SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT')",
(int) $stid);
$q3 = mysqli_query($link,$q);
```